# Error with application launch - no sRGB texture formats found

Tags: ubuntu, display

I'm trying to launch PSI browser used in proctored exam.
But it fails saying this error message.

--

expecting AppImage to succeed.

"no sRGB texture formats found"

--

As such, the monitor has good resolution.

Do I need to install any package to overcome this error?

My ubuntu version:
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Thanks!